# spring not working with multiple properties files

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

This question may sound old but I am not able to use multiple `properties` files as after looking for solution I came to know that for validator class I  added `hibernate validator 4,5,Jboss Logging final jars` and now Its saying

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1197783': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'validator' while setting bean property 'validator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springDispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
```

and this is my `configuration file`

```
<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"
        validator="validator" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.*" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
<mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
                <property name="paramName" value="language" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        value="/com/resources/messages,/com/resources/messages_validation.properties"
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    </bean>

    <bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource" />
    </bean>
```

**name of properties file (they are in same folder)**

```
messages_en.properties
messages_nl.properties
messages_validations.properties
```

I am not able to understand why It is giving me error if everything is in right place

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:com/resources/messages</value>
                <value>classpath:com/resources</value>                
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: I have one doubt, will spring automatically pick other `properties` class?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work assuming your messageproperties is under /com/resources

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:/com/resources/messages/" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"/>
</bean>
```